# How to deploy "Organization Business Hours" from one sandbox to another sandbox

Tags: deployment

I am deploying some component to a sandbox by using ChangeSet

I want to deploy "`Organization Business Hours`" But unable to find any component to add into ChangeSet.

I'd be glad, if someone could tell me under what component it falls under?

Answer (score 3):

There is fix set of components available for deploying through change set.

In that fix list “Organization Business Hours” is not included.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_about_components.htm&language=en_US

So you will have do this change manually on production.

Here is quote from manual for your reference:

> If you create or modify components that aren’t available in a change set, you can't send those components from one organization to another in a change set. In this case, migrate the changes manually by repeating the steps you performed when you created or modified the component.

Comment: If I am going for Eclipse IDE, then what component I should go for?

Comment: What ever you see under **src** folder that you can deploy using IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Businesshours: This object is used to specify the business hours of your support organization.

Supported calls: create(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve(), update()

so the above Businesshoursobject[image: Business hours records] can be updated via API using tools like dataloader/jitter bit dataloader/soql explorer

Answer (score 0):

Look for Business hours under the Setting to get list of Holidays and Business hours Mapping.

```
<types>
    <members>BusinessHours</members>
    <name>Settings</name>
</types>
```